# 'CsGL.OSLib' threw an exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I'm starting with OpenGL for C#, so I downloaded and installed CsGL library, but when I'm trying to run some sample solutions Visual Studio throws exception

> the type initializer for 'csgl.oslib' threw an exception".

How to fix it?

Comment: Use OpenTK instead. CsGl has not been updated since 2003, and only wraps OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

- Set the target platform to x86 (in project properties>build)
- Copy both dll's (`csgl.dll` + `csgl.native.dll`) to 'C:\Windows\System32' AND 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64'

You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Commonly it means than static constructor in `CsGL.OSLib` thrown an error. Try to get more details in `InnerException` of your exception. Perhaps, some dependent libraries are missing.

I found [this](http://www.codeforge.com/read/141714/OSLib.cs__html) source code of `CsGL.OSLib` in internet. Is it your project? Check `CsGL.OSLib` static constructor.